# Query a list of custom dimension keys

Tags: azure-application-insights

I'm looking to build a distinct list of all the custom dimension keys that exist in a set of results. I can't find a function to isolate the key names. 
The closest I can find is mvexpand but that still keeps each key/value pair in a dictionary.

Is there an application insights function to extract key names from a dictionary?

Answer (score 3):

If you do `| mvexpand bagexpansion=array` you'll be able to address the column names as you would with an array index via `customDimensions[0]`:

```
| mvexpand bagexpansion=array customDimensions
| distinct tostring(customDimensions[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for us:

```
traces
| project (customDimensions)
| extend keybag = bag_keys(customDimensions)
| mv-expand (keybag)
| extend property = tostring(keybag)
| distinct property
| order by property asc
```